# Mouse pointer out of control

Tags: mouse-pointer

Sometimes I get the problem of my mouse pointer is out of control, I can execute the left click but I can't control the position of my mouse control.
This problem only occurs me when I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 because for a few time I' was using Elementary OS, I never had this problem.

Comment: I'm using laptop

Comment: Are you referring to your laptop's trackpad or an external mouse? By "out of control" do you mean the mouse pointer moves strangely or that it doesn't move at all?

Comment: I'm referring that my mouse pointer moves strangely, but when I disable the trackpad, the pointer doesn't move. If I connect an external mouse after disabled the trackpad, I can move normally the mouse pointer.